# How do you determine the cause of a failed Auth::attempt in Laravel 4?

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

When authenticating a user in Laravel 4, the `Auth::attemp(..)` method returns false if the authentication failed.  Is there a way to narrow down why it failed so I can indicate to my users whether, for example, it was the password vs their username that was in error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No direct one, but you can always:

```
if ( ! User::where('email', Input::get('email'))->first())
{
    /// email's wrong
}
else
{
    if ( ! Auth::attempt(['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' => Input::get('password')])
    {
        /// password's wrong
    }
}
```

If you need to give this information to your user, there's nothing wrong in doing this.

Comment: If you are sensitive about the security of you site, you shouldn't tell a user what is wrong with their failed login attempt.  If you don't require much security then go ahead.

Comment: This is an argument tha has been used a lot in the past years, but I think that are other ways to ensure security, like not letting a user try a password for the same e-mail more than twice in the same minute or so. And Mailchimp has other reasons to not worry about this kind of security matter too: https://blog.mailchimp.com/social-login-buttons-arent-worth-it/.

Comment: Interesting link @Antonio

Comment: what if system checks also for "banned" user (email/pass combination can be ok but banned flag is not ok) I would love to be able to determine error...